# ImportError: cannot import name '_init_centroids' from 'sklearn.cluster._kmeans

Tags: python, scikit-learn, k-means

I am working with python 3.8.8, Tensorflow-gpu:2.4.1 and version of scikit-learn is 0.24.2.

With old version I did not have this problem, but I had to upgrade my python and tensorflow to be able to run my code on gpu.
error is

```
from sklearn.cluster._kmeans import _init_centroids
ImportError: cannot import name '_init_centroids' from 'sklearn.cluster._kmeans'
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 5):

The method `_init_centroids` no longer exists for the module `_kmeans`. It is now a method of the `KMeans` class instead.

```
>>> from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
>>> KMeans._init_centroids?
    Signature:
    KMeans._init_centroids(
        self,
        X,
        x_squared_norms,
        init,
        random_state,
        init_size=None,
    )
    Docstring:
    Compute the initial centroids.
    
    Parameters
    ----------
    X : {ndarray, sparse matrix} of shape (n_samples, n_features)
        The input samples.
    
    x_squared_norms : ndarray of shape (n_samples,)
        Squared euclidean norm of each data point. Pass it if you have it
        at hands already to avoid it being recomputed here.
    
    init : {'k-means++', 'random'}, callable or ndarray of shape                 (n_clusters, n_features)
        Method for initialization.
    
    random_state : RandomState instance
        Determines random number generation for centroid initialization.
        See :term:`Glossary <random_state>`.
    
    init_size : int, default=None
        Number of samples to randomly sample for speeding up the
        initialization (sometimes at the expense of accuracy).
    
    Returns
    -------
    centers : ndarray of shape (n_clusters, n_features)
    File:      c:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cluster\_kmeans.py
    Type:      function
```

That means that, if you absolutely need to use the method `_init_centroids`, you have to use it from the class `KMeans`. Check the [source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/15a949460/sklearn/cluster/_kmeans.py#L953) and you'll see that `_init_centroids` is a method inside `class KMeans(...)`. Here is an example use

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)

X = np.random.randn(100, 2) # random data

# define your model
model = KMeans(n_clusters=2)

# call _init_centroids
centroids = model._init_centroids(X, init='k-means++', 
                                  x_squared_norms=None,
                                  random_state=np.random.RandomState(seed=0))

>>> centroids
    array([[-1.07075262,  1.05445173],
           [ 0.85683061, -0.65102559]])
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I didn't use the method directly. Actually I am new to Python and now I wanted to use some code from GitHub but Ive encountered this problem. 
  File "C:\Users\anaconda3\site-packages\pyriemann\clustering.py", line 5, in <module>
    from sklearn.cluster._kmeans import _init_centroids

ImportError: cannot import name '_init_centroids' from 'sklearn.cluster._kmeans' (C:\Users\anaconda3\site-packages\sklearn\cluster\_kmeans.py)

Comment: @Elmi please do **not** post code or error messages in the comments - they are literally unreadable! And in any case, why are you repeating here what you have already said in your question?

Comment: @Elmi, check my updated answer. I added an example use to make it a little more clear.